# Withdraw and Deposit with Recursion

Tags: python, recursion

So I've just started working on this to practice my experience with recursion. I have my code here and for some reason it only lets me use the withdrawal part of it and not the deposit:

```
def recursive(n):
    print("You have $", n, "In the bank!")
    option = (input("Do you want to withdraw or deposit?"))    
    if option == "withdraw" or "Withdraw":
        withdraw = int(input("How much do you want to withdraw from your account?"))
        recursive(n - withdraw)

    elif option == "deposit" or "Deposit":
        deposit = int(input("How much do you want to deposit?"))
        recursive(n + deposit)

    else:
        print("Not a valid option!")
        print("Shutting Down!")

def money(n):
    if n < 0:
        print("You are out of money!")

def main():
    recursive(100)

main()
```

Please let me know my error here!

Comment: @QPaysTaxes It would only let me do the withdraw part of it even if i entered deposit

Comment: For the future, you're expected to put all of the relevant information into the question itself. It's not too bad when it's in the comments, but it's much neater when it's all in one place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change:

```
if option == "withdraw" or "Withdraw":
```

to:

```
if option == "withdraw" or option == "Withdraw":
```

and do the same for `deposit` as well.